# The solution of the Euler-Bernoulli equation via separation of variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem

I'm trying to solve the Euler-Bernoulli equation for a beam for a construction with a solution in the form of $w(\zeta,t) = f(\zeta)g(t)$ (separation of variables). However, it is mentioned that this can still be tricky, but since the beam is undamped, we can assume $ g(t) = e^{i \lambda t}$ with $\lambda$ real.

**My first question is; why is the above choice logical to assume?**

(does this have anything to do with $e^{i \lambda t} = cos(\lambda t) + i sin(\lambda t)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$)

I made a beginning with the separation of variable technique:

The Euler-Bernoulli equation:

$\rho\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial t^{2}}(\zeta,t) = -EI\frac{\partial^{4}w}{\partial \zeta^{4}}(\zeta,t),\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\zeta \in [0,1], t \geq 0$

With boundary conditions:

$w(0,t) = w(1,t), \frac{\partial w}{\partial \zeta}(0,t) = \frac{\partial w}{\partial \zeta}(1,t)$

Substituting $w(\zeta,t) = f(\zeta)g(t)$ in the Euler-Bernoulli equation gives:

$\rho\frac{\partial^{2}f(\zeta)g(t)}{\partial t^{2}}(\zeta,t) = -EI\frac{\partial^{4}f(\zeta)g(t)}{\partial \zeta^{4}}(\zeta,t)$

$f(\zeta)\rho\frac{\partial^{2}g(t)}{\partial t^{2}}(\zeta,t) = -EIg(t)\frac{\partial^{4}f(\zeta)}{\partial \zeta^{4}}(\zeta,t)$

Since space and time are in this case independent of each other, both sides have to be equal to the same constant -$\lambda$. This gives us a set of three qualities:

$
1. \frac{d^2g(t)}{dt^2} = -g(t)\lambda \\
2. \frac{d^4f(\zeta)}{d\zeta^4} = \rho f(t)\frac{\lambda}{EI} \\
3. w(0,t) = w(1,t) \rightarrow f(0) = f(1)
$

The general solution of g(t) (if positive) is:

$
g(t) = C_{1} * e^{-i \sqrt{\lambda}t} + C_{2} * e^{i \sqrt{\lambda}t}
$

Using Euler's formula, g(t) becomes:

$
g(t) = C_1 cos(\sqrt{\lambda}t) + C_2 sin(\sqrt{\lambda}t)
$

From here, I am pretty much stuck to find a proposed solution for $f(\zeta)$ and to determine the solution to this problem.

The second question now is how to determine a proposed solution for $f(\zeta)$ and how to determine the 3 lowest (strictly positive) $\lambda$'s such that $w(\zeta,t) = f(\zeta)e^{i\lambda t}$ is a non-zero solution of the Euler-Bernoulli equation?

Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

After solving for $f(\xi)$ we have

$$
f(\xi) = \sum_{k=1}^4 C_kf_k(\xi,\lambda)
$$

A typical $f_k(\xi,\lambda)$ is

$$
f_1(\xi,\lambda) = e^{\sqrt[4]{-\frac{\lambda}{EI}}\xi}
$$

Here $C_k$ are integration constants, so to accomplish with the boundary conditions we should solve the linear system

$$
f(0,\lambda)-f(1,\lambda) = 0\\
f'(0,\lambda)-f'(1,\lambda) = 0
$$

or

$$
M(\lambda)C = 0
$$

with

$$
C=\left(C1,C_2,C_3,C_4\right)^{\dagger}
$$

thus to have a non trivial solution for $C$ we need that  $\det\left(M(\lambda)\right) = 0$ and the roots for this equation furnish the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I have an expression for $f(\xi)$ now. Do you have any idea why $g(t) = e^{i \lambda t}$ can be assumed for an undamped beam?

Comment: Time is introduced in the study of beams, when you want to model the dynamic behavior, as in the case of vibrations. Then elastic waves propagate along the beam and this formulation is essential.